# Google Play Game Services Save Data Online

Tags: android, google-play-games

How can I save data online with google play game services? or better,can I save data online?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the **[Cloud Save](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/cloudsave)**. This service allows you to store application data for each user of an application on Google's servers. Your application can retrieve and update this user data from Android devices, iOS devices, or web applications by using the Cloud Save APIs.

This service makes it possible to synchronize data for each user of an application across multiple devices and platforms. For example, if you have a game that runs on Android, iOS, and the web, you can use the Cloud Save service to allow a user to start a game on their Android phone, and then continue playing on a tablet, iOS device, or web browser without losing any of their progress. This service can also be used to ensure that a user's game play continues from where it left off even if their device is lost, destroyed, or traded in for a newer model.

Comment: Can you post a piece of code please?

Comment: Yes, of course. You have a sample game that use the **Cloud Saves** API and the conflict management in this link: [Collect All the Stars](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads). Please do not forget to accept the answer.